# Redux in WebSocket Server

Tags: reactjs, redux, websocket, react-redux

I am building a multiplayer game using React, Redux and WebSockets. What I'd like to know is if it is "allowed" to use Redux on the server-side. I would like to use it as follows:

- Dispatch an action on the client-side.
- Intercept the action with middleware.
- Send the action to the server via a WebSocket.
- Dispatch the received action on the server-side.
- Handle the action using a reducer.

The same principle could be used to send an action from the server to the client. (Just the other way around)

I feel like this should work and not cause any problems, but I can't find anything regarding wether Redux could be used server-side or wether it is a good idea to do so. Can someone please tell me more about this?

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search would bring you to an in depth article on why this is a bad idea. https://blog.bitsrc.io/can-redux-be-used-on-the-server-e2d3ecbf7ee4

> This brings us to the major reason why you wouldn’t use Redux as-is on
>   the server: it was designed to hold transient state. But the
>   application state stored on the backend is usually meant to be
>   long-lived. If you used a Redux store on your Node.js server, the
>   state would be cleared every time the node process stops. On a PHP
>   server, the state would be cleared on every request.

Redux is designed for front end state management, people typically use persistent databases for backend applications.

Comment: I've read that one, yes. However, it doesn't really matter if all data gets lost when the process ends. The game I'm making is kind of like chess. I only need to store the data for as long as the game is active.

Comment: But backend processes don't work like that, every HTTP request would be a new process, so the data would not be there for your entire chess game.

Comment: I'm using WebSockets. As long as the process is there, every client has access to the data within the WebSocket server.

Comment: I guess you can do what you want then, I am just telling you it is a bad idea to design your application's state to be dependent on a process staying open.  That is what you asked.  Imagine your websocket loses connection (happens a lot and most libraries have reconnect built in), you will lose all of that state

Comment: When your WebSocket loses connection, wouldn't the state on the server still be there? That process is still running. And even then; if you lose connection, you're out of the game. That's not a problem for wha I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Keeping the process open would need to be implemented in your backend logic, my original point though is designing your application's state based on keeping a socket open is bad design in my opinion.  There are much better alternatives, such as using a lightweight database, which is why you can't find much documentation on what you are attempting.